# Looping through different ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am working of a vba code to check cells in a retain range for criterium1. then i need to loop through other ranges to check for other criteria2,3,4... My range must then be variable. It loops column by column, always between rows 3 and "lr" whch is a variable. I also have the column number a variable "col" since this is the variable I must increments to loop. I wrote this but it's not working.
In my For Each loop I also call upon other functions. these functions are called "CriteriaCol1", "CriteriaCol2", and so on. so the column number and the number in the Sub im calling are the same. So is there a way of making the number in the sub title a variable too? Here is a bit of confusing code:

```
Sub error_rept()

Dim lr As Long
Dim colrg As Range
Dim col As Integer
Dim Passed As Boolean

    lr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    col = 1

    Do While col < 8

        set colrg=sheets("NewDataSheet").range(col,3:col,lr)
            For Each cell In colrg
                '##if "run CriteriaCol1 and check if value of passed is true or false" then
                    Next
                Else
                    'do something
                End If
            Next

End Sub

Sub CriteriaCol()

Dim passes As Boolean

    If (cell.Value) = 6.01 Or (cell.Value) = 6.03 Or (cell.Value) = 6.04 Or (cell.Value) = 6.27 Then
        Passed = True
    Else
        Passed = False
    End If

End Sub

Sub CriteriaCol2()

Dim Passed As Boolean

    If (cell.Value) < 9999 And (cell.Value) > 1000 Then
        Passed = True
    Else
        Passed = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The line set colrg gives error: syntax error

any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Please show the context code. One single line is not enough to understand the problem. Also, please mention which error code you get.

Comment: @user2385809 .. have you try myanswer ? .. got any error ?

Comment: I expanded my question above. I know it's a lillte confusing. Let me know if you dont understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
set colrg=sheets("NewDataSheet").range(format(col) & "3:" & format(col) & format(lr))
```

Comment: ah Thanks this seemed to work. I expanded my question though for one of the comments

Comment: @user2385809 .. if this answer help you figured out your `colrg` problem, feel free to make a green tick below downvote sign .. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of setting a range is by using the Cells() method. To set a range object to be "B2:C5", for example, you'd use something like the following:

```
set colrg = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(5,3))
```

Since (2, 2) corresponds to the second row and second column, B2 and (5, 3) corresponds to the fifth row and third column, C5.

You can then loop through this range using a For Each with a variant or cell object.

Comment: Danzomida: careful, this often hides bugs when working with multiple sheets. You should either always ignore the sheet and use the default `Range(Cells(2,2), Cells(5,3))` or always specify it `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,2), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5,3))`

Comment: That's interesting. Can you give an example where my version would be a problem?

Comment: Try to make a function `Function GetA1(Sh)|Sh.Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(1,1)|End Function`, make a test function that calls `GetA1(Sheet1)` and `GetA1(Sheet2)`, then select Sheet1 and call the test function: the second call will fail because can't find the `Cells(1,1)` in Sheet2, because a call to `Cells` without the object defaults to `ActiveSheet`, which is Sheet1. This used to get me all the time in functions that `Sort` multiple sheets, and I just put `Key1:=Range()`, which wouldn't work if the active sheet wasn't the sorted one.

Comment: I see. That makes sense for the situation where you are writing a generic function like that, thanks.